# Force Zend Framework to connect to database earlier than usual

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db

I am trying to store custom routes for the Zend Framework inside the database. I have the process down that will create the route, but the problem I am running into is that when I am adding the routes it looks like Zend has not yet created its connection to the database.

Does anyone know where this processes initially happens or how I can force the database to connect from the init_routes function inside Bootstrap.php?

UPDATE:

What I am doing from Bootstrap.php is calling a model that will return all the Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Static objects for the vendors. Here is the code I am using inside Bootstrap.php

```
$frontController = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$router = $frontController->getRouter();

$vendor_routes = new Application_Model_Vendor();
$vendor_routes = $vendor_routes->getStaticRoutes();
```

The code inside the getStaticRoutes() function is as follows:

```
public function getStaticRoutes() {
    $select = $this->select();
    $select->from($this)
        ->where("featured = 1");
    $rows = $this->fetchAll($select);

    foreach($rows as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
}
```

This function is contained in a model that extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract

The error that I am getting is as follows:

```
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message 'No adapter found for Application_Model_Vendor' in /var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php:754
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(739): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract-&gt;_setupDatabaseAdapter()
#1 /var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(268): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract-&gt;_setup()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/application/Bootstrap.php(17): Zend_Db_Table_Abstract-&gt;__construct()
#3 /var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(666): Bootstrap-&gt;_initRoutes()
#4 /var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(619): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-&gt;_executeResource('routes')
#5 /var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/library/Zend/Application/Bootstrap/BootstrapAbstract.php(583): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_BootstrapAbstract-&gt;_bootstrap(NUL in <b>/var/www/vhosts/weddingdir/weddingdir/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php</b> on line <b>754</b><br />
```

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should connect on demand. If you have an equivalent init method for initialising your database connection, you just need to ensure that this is bootstrapped before your routes, like this:

```
protected function _initRoutes()
{
    // this will trigger the _initDb method. 'db' should match
    // the name of that method
    $this->bootstrap('db');

    // routes stuff here
}

protected function _initDb()
{
    // db stuff here
}
```

Edit: okay, looks like you just need to tell Zend_Db_Table to use your DB connection. In code you'd do:

```
Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
```

in application.ini I think you can do:

```
resources.db.isDefaultTableAdapter = true
```

which I'm guessing you don't currently have. See if that fixes your issue. See the DB section on http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.application.available-resources.html for a fuller example.

Comment: My Bootstrap.php does not have the _initDb() inside of it. I would assume it connects to the database when it needs to (it does everywhere else in the application) but inside of Bootstrap it does not. I am thinking that its because the database connection info is stored in the application.ini file and that it maybe has not parsed that file yet or something.

Comment: The application.ini stuff is run before all of the _init methods, so you should be fine. Can you post an example of how you are accessing/using the db class in your route method? $this->getResource('db'); should give you the DB class as setup by your application.ini data, so you could try var_dump()'ing that to see what you get.

Comment: Thanks. I think you just need to set the default adapter for Zend_Db_Table - I've edited my answer to include an example of how to do this.

Comment: This is indeed the right approach. You must bootstrap the 'db' in your initRoutes method first to make sure it is initialised.